# Any way to make {% extends '...' %} conditional? - Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-templates

I would like to share a template between AJAX and regular HTTP calls, the only difference is that one template needs to be served with the `base.html` html, the other one without.

Any idea?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use a variable.

```
{% extends base_template %}
```

and in your view, set it to "base.html" in your view, or a new "ajax.html" file which just provides the block and nothing else.

Comment: One problem: This breaks django-compressor offline compression.

Answer (score 135):

The other answers require you to pass an additional context variable. But as long as you can access the request object, there is no need:

```
{% extends request.is_ajax|yesno:"app/base_ajax.html,app/base.html" %}
```

I found this to be much more convenient.

Comment: Any way to include `{% block 'someblock' %}` in a similar dynamic way?

Comment: Super handy, we are A/B testing and rolling out new UI and the variable route would cause a ton of work. You deserve the green check as this answers the question.

Comment: This solves the django-compressor offline compression issue.

Comment: @TheoKouzelis how does it solve the compression issue? In my understanding, in this case `django-compressor` will create a cache for the `app/base.html` case but not for the `app/base_ajax.html` which will fail when attempting to load the cached template (no key in the generated offline manifest).

Answer (score 30):

```
{% extends override_base|default:'base.html' %}
```

P.s. I know this is an old question, but I found it when searching for an answer.  Maybe it'll help someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

You can use {% extends variable %}

Pass a variable base template name in when you create the context in the view.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#extends