# Django templates different extends keyword

Tags: django, django-templates

Is the following permitted in Django templates

```
{% if user.get_profile.usertype == "Administrator"%}
  {% extends "base/admin_base.html" %}
{% else %}
   {% if user.get_profile.usertype == "Guest" %}
     {% extends "base/guest_base.html" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Extending another template must be the *first* thing a child template does, even before loading tag libraries.

Comment: @Rajeev - See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380984/any-way-to-make-extends-conditional-django).