# Django: making {% block "div" %} conditional with a conditional {% extends %}

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I would like to share a template between AJAX and regualr HTTP calls, the only difference is that one template needs to extend base.html html, while the other dose not.

I can use

```
{% extends request.is_ajax|yesno:"app/base_ajax.html,app/base.html" %}
```

To dynamically decide when to extend, but I also need to include `{% block 'some_div' %}{% endbock %}` tags to tell the renderer where to put my content. The ajax call needs those tags to be left out because jQuery tells it where to put the content with `$('somediv').html(response)`.

*Any idea on how to dynamically include those block tags when its not an ajax call?*

I've been referencing this question to figure it out:

[Any way to make {% extends '...' %} conditional? - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380984/any-way-to-make-extends-conditional-django)

#### Attempt to make it work through an {% if %}:

```
{% extends request.is_ajax|yesno:",stamped/home.html" %}
{% if request.is_ajax == False%}
{% block results %}
{% endif %}
{% load stamped_custom_tags %}

...
Content
...
{% if request.is_ajax == False%}
{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

but this fails when parser runs into the {% endif %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

```
{% extends x|yesno:"stamped/blank.html,stamped/home.html" %}
```

Where `blank.html` contains:

```
{% block results %}{% endblock %}

<!-- to allow for corrected shared rendering 
    with ajax posts and normal django rendering -->
```

and `home.html` is my standard app page with a results block to extend.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this, or some variant, do?

```
{% if request.is_ajax %}
    {# ajax! #}
{% else %}
    {% block 'some_div' %}{% endbock %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob, but I'd have to repeat the template twice. Once without block tags in your ajax section and once within the block tags. This would be just as bad as two separate templates with identical content, and is the exact thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No you wouldn't. Make the template, and when you get to the part where the block tag goes, use the conditional. If it's ajax, nothing will be there (just a comment), if it's not, the block will go there.

Comment: Have you tried it? I was trying to do something just like this before I posted my question. I have to wrap the block tags around the content so I need two conditionals; one for the start of the block and one for the end. the problem is that the parser gets confused when it sees the endif after the first {% block 'some_div' %}. I couldn't get past the parser before, which led me to my post here. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a simple version of your template so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Yeah, that cant work. You can't have a conditional interrupting a block (what if only one were true?). I don't get what you're trying to accomplish with that.

Comment: Because I need to wrap the content in blocks for non ajax posts. I dont think there is anyway around it. Right?  see my last comment and question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36360/discussion-between-rob-l-and-agconti)