# Compress js on condition

Tags: django, django-templates, django-compressor

I have this code:

```
{% if not variable %}                                                                                                        
{% compress js %}                                                                                                                             
  <script src="{% static "js/init.js" %}"></script>                                                                                             
{% endcompress %}                                                                                                                             
{% endif %}
```

When I enable the compressor, the script is always active, when the variable is True too.

Comment: There is no easy way, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18638131/2011147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried writing a wrapper around the `compress` template tag that accepts a conditional as an argument? Theoretically this wrapper could just combine the `if` and `compress` tags to give you the result you want.

See the [Writing Custom Template Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) section of the Django docs for more information on writing your own template tags.

Also, check out the [compress template tag](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/blob/develop/compressor/templatetags/compress.py) from the `django-compressor` source code on Github.

Comment: Yes it is no easy way, anyway the easiest way is to modify the init.js and call it inside an if block without compress.