# Is it possible to preprocess a template to remove its `{% extends %}` tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

**Scenario**

I'm building an SPA and need to be able to render 3rd party app templates as partials within some of the pages. So they can't include any of the existing base.html markup.

**Problem**

I only need this to occur for some of the templates from a specific 3rd party app, as some of its views will still need to be rendered outside of the SPA as individual pages. So i can't just simply create my own base.html file with nothing in it, to prevent the other markup from being added, as this would affect every template.

At the moment, even though i'm not actually changing the templates in any way, i'm having to create like for like duplicates of those specific templates, which simply remove `{% extends "base.html" %}` from the top.

**Question**

Is there a way to preprocess only a specific template and remove its `{% extends %}` tag?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i actually needed...

[Any way to make {% extends '...' %} conditional? - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380984/any-way-to-make-extends-conditional-django/7817990#7817990)

... and below is the solution i spent several hours coming up with, until i finally realised the question i actually wanted to ask. I'm going to post it here anyway, just incase someone else finds it useful.

**__init__.py**

`{% extends %}` always has to be first in a template, so it's not possible to use `{% load %}` to load this tag. Instead it must be loaded in the same way as the django tags.

So this needs to go somewhere that will force it to run immediately.

```
# The `add_to_builtins` function changed module in 1.7
try:
    from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins
except ImportError:
    from django.template.base import add_to_builtins


add_to_builtins('my_app.templatetags.overriden_tags')
```

**my_app/templatetags/overriden_tags.py**

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader_tags import do_extends, ExtendsNode

register = template.Library()

@register.tag('extends')
def preventable_extends(parser, token):
    node = do_extends(parser, token)
    return PreventableExtendsNode(node.nodelist, node.parent_name)


class PreventableExtendsNode(ExtendsNode):

    def render(self, context):
        prevent = context.get('prevent_extends')
        if prevent == self.parent_name.var:
            return self.nodelist.render(context)
        return super(PreventableExtendsNode, self).render(context)
```

**mixins.py**

```
class PreventableExtendsMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.prevent_extends = kwargs.pop('prevent_extends')
        super(PreventableExtendsMixin, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PreventableExtendsMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['prevent_extends'] = self.prevent_extends
        return context
```

**Usage**

```
from third_party_app import LoginView

class MyLoginView(PreventableExtendsMixin, LoginView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['prevent_extends'] = 'base.html'
        super(MyLoginView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```