# Can I use djangocms plugins in a conditional extended page?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I have this at the top of my djangocms page template

```
{% extends request.user.is_authenticated|yesno:"member_template.html,base.html" %}
```

My plugins are not working with this setup. But if I do this

```
{% extends "member_template.html" %}
```

My plugins work. Is there a way to fix that? I want that conditional.

Comment: Have you thought of this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5381015/1757321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you're using render in your view.

```
if request.user: base_file = "member_template.html"
else: base_file = base.html
render(request,'my_html.html',
               {'base_file' : base_file})
```

And then your extends tag looks like:

```
{% extends base_file %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put an if statement in?

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %} {% extends "member_template.html" %}
{% else %} {% extends "base.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: No, the first line in a template must be extend. If I do what you suggested, it gives an error.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  But extends also needs to be followed immediately by either the file it extends or a variable that evaluates to the file so you'll need a tag or include it in the context

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I am clueless about this.

Comment: @DharienCthaeh Have you thought of this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5381015/1757321

Comment: @DharienCthaeh see example in separate answer