# Django - How to dynamically choose base template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to choose which base template to use in my Django project from a possible three options. I sourced online and, from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381015/10907303), I saw:

> Use a variable.
>
> `{% extends base_template %}`
>
> and in your view, set it to "base.html" in your view, or a new
> "ajax.html" file which just provides the block and nothing else.

But a comment to that answer reads:

> This breaks django-compressor offline compression.

1. I do not know what that means

Another answer said:

> `{% extends request.is_ajax|yesno:"app/base_ajax.html,app/base.html" %}`

But I am not making `AJAX` request. From this answer, I discovered the `yesno` Django provides.
This works just for `True` or `False`; more like `if-else` statement.
How can I achieve `if`, `else` and `else-if` statements ? Because that seems to be one way I could achieve what I am trying to achieve. But if you have better options, please pour it out.

Here is what I tried

```
{% if user_type == 1 %}
{% extends 'hod_template/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% elif user_type == 2 %}
{% extends 'staff_template/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% else %}
{% extends 'student_template/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% endif %}
```

But I got `Invalid block tag on line 4: 'elif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?` as error.

Comment: why do you need that? you can have differenct templates and in view choose one that you need

Comment: A common operation for all users. I don't wanna repeat same code.

Comment: I think it is actually a relevant question, because you may want to pick to base template based on the domain and it seems to be that it cannot be done within the template itself, as it was shown in the question.